# Problem: Pyinstaller installing FPDF2-Module -> module not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller, fpdf

I have installed fpdf2 with pip and afterwards I want to Installing it as a .exe with pyinstaller (Python 3.9). The code is running in the script, but after installing and starting the .exe I got from the .exe the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fpdf'
```

Pip installing:

```
`pip install fpdf2`
```

Command for pyinstaller:

`pyinstaller example.py --onefile`

Code of Example.py:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF(orientation="P", unit="mm", format="A4")
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_left_margin(20)
pdf.set_right_margin(20)
pdf.set_top_margin(25)
pdf.set_font("helvetica", "", 16)
text_for_pdf = "Hello World"
pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, txt=text_for_pdf)
pdf.output("hello_world.pdf")
```

I have already updated all the modules and my Python version is 3.9.
I have also tried:

```
pyinstaller example.py --onefile --hidden-import "fpdf"
```

I hope you understand my problem, thank you for helping my out!
Best regards

Comment: What happens if you call python <script name> from that place?

Comment: it runs normally, also the creating of the .exe is successfully, the error message comes after starting the finished .exe

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the pyinstaller version 4.10!
With the newest version of pyinstaller 5.7.0 it worked out!
So the version 4.10 didn't work togehter with FPDF2!